# Order of initialization in class

Tags: java, class, inheritance

Why is it that class variables are initialiazed before constructor gets called if the class in question isn't extending any other class but constructor gets called first and than initialization of class variables are done if the class in question is extending some other class!

e.g. let's say i have a class

```
public class Windows {
    public Windows() {
        System.out.println("in window");
    }
}
```

and i have one base class.

```
public class BaseClass {
    public BaseClass() {
        System.out.println("in base");
    }
}
```

and finally i have one more class.

```
public class ChildClass extends BaseClass {

Windows w = new Windows();

public ChildClass() {
    System.out.println("in subclass");

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new ChildClass());
}
}
```

will result in

> in base
>   in window
>   in subclass

which suggests that base class constructor got called which means childclass constructor got called, but after baseclass constructor finished, why did field got initialized? i.e. shouldn't it be something like

> in base
>   in subclass
>   in window

That will explain something!

Again if i do

```
public class ChildClass {

Windows w = new Windows();

public ChildClass() {
    System.out.println("in subclass");

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new ChildClass());
}
}
```

i'll get

> in window
>   in subclass

which suggest that before constructor window field got initialized. Confused!?!?!? The picture gets even confusing if i add some static fields too!

Some explanation would be that JVM first initializes baseclass stuff first, then comes to current class's fields and finally the constructor. Is it true?

Some explanation will be great!!

Comment: You might wanna check this out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2

Comment: If only there was some sort of specification that detailed the Java language, like, say, a Java Language Specification.

Comment: Terminology please. There are no 'class variables' here. They would be static. There are *instance* variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best friend regarding Java is the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html). Regarding your question, you can find the answer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5):

> Just before a reference to the newly created object is returned as the
>   result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new
>   object using the following procedure:
>
> 1. Assign the arguments for the constructor to newly created parameter variables for this constructor invocation.
> 2. If this constructor begins with an explicit constructor invocation (§8.8.7.1) of another constructor in the same class (using this), then
>      evaluate the arguments and process that constructor invocation
>      recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor
>      invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly
>      for the same reason; otherwise, continue with step 5.
> 3. This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation of another constructor in the same class (using this). If
>      this constructor is for a class other than Object, then this
>      constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a
>      superclass constructor (using super). Evaluate the arguments and
>      process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using these
>      same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly,
>      then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise,
>      continue with step 4.
> 4. Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class, assigning the values of instance variable
>      initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the
>      left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source code
>      for the class. If execution of any of these initializers results in an
>      exception, then no further initializers are processed and this
>      procedure completes abruptly with that same exception. Otherwise,
>      continue with step 5.
> 5. Execute the rest of the body of this constructor. If that execution completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly
>      for the same reason. Otherwise, this procedure completes normally.

Comment: However you picked a strange place to look. You should have started with the JLS.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... JLS ?= Java Language Specification?